# pandas merge two dataframes based on nearest coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have two dataframes which are made up of columns `x`,`y`,`val` where (`x` and `y` are the Cartesian coordinate of the data point)
eg.

```
df1

x y    val
----------
0 0    1.1
1 1    1.2
0 5    1.3
```

```
df2

x   y       val
---------------
0   0.1     2.1
1   1.3     2.2
1.1 5       2.3
0   0       2.5
```

they can be of different length

I want to merge these based on the closest corresponding data point, to give me something like

```
val1      val2
---------------
1.1       2.1
1.2       2.2
1.3       2.3
1.1       2.5
```

**What I have tried**

I have had converted the dataframe into a list of coordinates and a list of values then used
`scipy.spatial.KDTree` to find the nearest neighbour, but this is terribly inefficent and takes a very long time to do (the dataframes have over 30k rows).

```py
x = []
y = []

for idx, coord in enumerate(var1Coords):

    if var1Vals[idx] is None:
        continue
    distance, index = spatial.KDTree(var2Coords).query(coord)
    if var2Vals[index] is None:
        continue

    y.append(var2Vals[index])
    x.append(var1Vals[idx])
```

If anyone has any way to do this with only pandas (ideal) or any other efficient way, I would greatly appreciated guidance as to what to try.

Comment: Have a look at [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

Comment: I have already had a look at `pd.merge_asof`, but It only does it by one column not two, so it wouldn't work for my scenario

Comment: You can be creative and merge them in one column as strings with `-` as separator for example

Comment: So what you are saying is to have a column with a cooridnate string in the format "x-y". If that is what u are saying I don't think I can use pd.merge_asof on that as pd.merge_asof only takes columns of `numeric column, such as datetimelike, integer, or float.` according gto the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) from `scipy`:

#### Solution:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

output = pd.DataFrame()
output["val1"] = pd.Series([df1["val"].iloc[np.argmin(x)] for x in cdist(df2[["x", "y"]], df1[["x","y"]])])
output["val2"] = df2["val"]

>>> output
   val1  val2
0   1.1   2.1
1   1.2   2.2
2   1.3   2.3
3   1.1   2.5
```

#### Explanation:

1. Get the matrix of distances using `cdist`:

```
>>> cdist(df2[["x", "y"]], df1[["x","y"]])
array([[0.1       , 1.3453624 , 4.9       ],
       [1.64012195, 0.3       , 3.83275358],
       [5.11957029, 4.0012498 , 1.1       ],
       [0.        , 1.41421356, 5.        ]])
```

2. Use `numpy.argmin` and `iloc` to get the value of the nearest point from the other DataFrame:

```
>>> [df1["val"].iloc[np.argmin(x)] for x in cdist(df2[["x", "y"]], df1[["x","y"]])]
[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1]
```

3. Use `pandas.concat` to form the required DataFrame.

###### Note:

If you have two equally near points, this will just give you the first one.

Comment: I tried this solution, but my `df1` contains 15M entries, so an incredibly large matrix is created with `cdist` and it crashes my kernel