# How to join/merge data tables based on close coordinates (using astropy or other methods)?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, inner-join, astropy

I have 2 astronomical tables, from a fits file and a csv file, that look something like this

```
ra, dec, val_a, val_b, ...
11.11, 22.22, 8, 9, ...
10.10, 20.20, 7, 6, ...
...
```

and this

```
ra, dec, val_x, val_y, ...
44.4, 55.55, 8, 9, ...
15.67, 23.45, 7, 6, ...
...
```

`ra` and `dec` are my astronomical coordinates (equivalent to latide and longitude on Earth). One table contains 15M galaxies and the other 80k. I would like to merge/cross-match the objects in these 2 tables with astropy, as long as corresponding objects have a separation smaller than a threshold distance in degrees. I know how to load the tables into astropy tables. And I know of the existence of [`skycoord`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord.html#astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord) and the [`join_skycoord`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.table.join_skycoord.html#astropy.table.join_skycoord) function. But I  am not able to apply them, because I don't find anywhere explained how when reading a table I specify `skycoord` columns or how I can later change the type of the columns to `skycoord` or how I can merge `skycoord` columns into my tables. I've tried also 2 other options presented [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/428102/205242) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68532614/5838180), but both resulted in my kernel crashing, because of the large amount of data.

Can someone provide me with code that can merge the 2 tables based on the sky coordinates? I would be also thankful for alternatives, that don't utilize astropy. Tnx

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to the source data?

Comment: Without considering specifics, just as a hint in a probable direction, consider that a good solution will not require O(NxM) memory or runtime; if you need to compare each galaxy in one table against each galaxy in the other, that will use quite a lot of memory, or runtime, or both. Instead, how might you order the two tables so you can walk forward through one table for some amount, then the other, and so on?  Or, what data structure would let you prune your search space without computationally expensive `sqrt`-type or `division`-type calculations?